# Limited Internet Access After Setting a Satic IP Address in Server 14.04

Tags: networking, static-ip

I edited my `/etc/network/interfaces` file for a static IP address.  It's listing is:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# The next two lines from the install (use DHCP for getting the address)  In the file they're
# commented out.
### auto eth0
### iface eth0 inet dhcp
#  set static IP address via code from askubuntu
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static 
    address 192.168.1.45 
    netmask 255.255.255.0 
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1
  # This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

The output of the ifconfig command is:

```
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:58:67:73:9d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.45  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:8074:46e0:8c2d:580:6494:c689/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:58ff:fe67:739d/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:8074:46e0:215:58ff:fe67:739d/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:26 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7062 (7.0 KB)  TX bytes:18917 (18.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:37566 (37.5 KB)  TX bytes:37566 (37.5 KB)
```

The problem is that FireFox will only access a few URLs.

Ones that work:

- www.att.com
- my.yahoo.com
- www.google.com
- www.buffalotech.com (via a Google search)

Sites that won't work:

- www.askubuntu.com
- www.buffalotech.com (not using Google)
- www.amazon.com
- Yahoo's login page
- Yahoo's mail page

I don't understand why some sites work and others don't.  I can ping to and from Ubuntu Server from other machines on my local network.

Could the issue involve IP6 protocol?  Maybe some sites are using it and others aren't. If I need to include a static IP6 address, how do I get its value(s)?

I would really appreciate help on this one. I'm trying to set the server up as a Samba primary domain controller and need to assign it a static IP address.

Comment: Please edit your question so that its format is reabable. If you need a static IP, set it from the Network Manager interface, and remember you have to set manually the default route and the DNS server (which is probably your problem here).

Comment: Try setting the DNS server as `8.8.8.8`/`8.8.4.4` (Google's). Broadcast is optional and switching from `auto eth0` to `allow-hotplug eth0` is recommended if you're not **always** connected to the cable.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself but I don't understand why it worked.  I installed the graphic network manager and re-entered the data from the network/interfaces file.

When I rebooted, I found that FireFox could access any URL I entered.  It appears the the graphical tool does something the DNS server address that the Network/interfaces file does not.

I hope this will help others.